# Prevent Creation of Default Schema

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

I am running the following code to create a `catalog`:

```
spark.sql("CREATE CATALOG  IF NOT EXISTS "+ "catalog " +
          "MANAGED LOCATION '" + managed_location +"'")
```

When trying to drop the catalog I get an error because a default schema was created automatically. **How can I prevent the creation of the default schema?**